# Lazy initialization of nullable member

Tags: kotlin

If we have a member variable defined as

```
private var foo: Foo? = null
```

and we want to initialize it when we call a method with an argument (which is needed to initialize Foo), is there a better way to do it than this?

```
fun generateFoo(bar: Bar): Foo {
    var localFoo = foo
    if (localFoo == null) {
        localFoo = Foo(bar)
        foo = localFoo
    }
    return localFoo
}
```

I'm looking at avoiding all the variable assignments.

Edit: a slightly shorter version is here, but still not ideal

```
fun generateFoo(bar: Bar): Foo {
    var localFoo = foo ?: Foo(bar)
    foo = localFoo
    return localFoo
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for having a local variable here at all?

Comment: Aren't there `lazy` and/or late init operators for just this purpose?

Comment: Lazy does not allow an argument, which is required here to initialize Foo.

Comment: @zsmb13 foo should be initialized only once, a local variable won't help.

Comment: @Francesc think zsmb meant that you do not need `localFoo` variable. The shortest possible way I can think of to do this is: `foo = foo ?: Foo(bar); return foo`

Comment: I've realized it since. You need it because you're returning a non-nullable `Foo` from the function.

Comment: This code has conceptual flaws. Consider calling `generateFoo` two times with different `bar`s. The second time it will return a `Foo` with the previous `Bar` instance, not the corresponding one.

Comment: @Mibaic it won't work, you can't return foo (a nullable) when the function declares a non-nullable return type.

Comment: You could do `return foo!!` and there shouldn't be a problem with it

Comment: @TamasHegedus that's irrelevant, this is an example - I'm asking if there is a better way to initialize a nullable with a dependency on an argument that is not known initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is safe unless you have multiple threads hitting your class:

```
fun generateFoo(bar: Bar): Foo {
    if (foo == null) {
        foo = Foo(bar)
    }
    return foo!!
}
```

But if you like, you can do things like this - up to you whether you think this is more readable than the longer version you already have:

```
fun generateFoo(bar: Bar) = foo ?: Foo(bar).also { foo = it }
```

Comment: Your first solution is no better than mine listed in the question, but the 2nd is more concise. While still not exactly what I'm after (I ideally would like a by lazy where we can pass an argument, but that might not exist), I'm accepting it as the correct answer.